# about the questions tagged [difference-equations] or [recurrence-relations]

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I discover that the questions tagged [difference-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-equations) or [recurrence-relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relations) are often similar. I also find difficulties to distinguish clearly between difference equations and recurrence relations. Moreover, the format of the equations in the two tags are often not unified. I know that there are two approaches: one for the domain of the independent variables are only needed to consider in integers (discrete version), and one for the domain of the independent variables should at least considered in real numbers (continuous version). In fact [this](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe-toc1.htm) has distinguished clearly that independent variables written as suffix mean that in discrete version while independent variables written in brackets means that in continuous version. But many users ignored the above two formats and they often lump together. These often make me very confused about whether the questions are considering in discrete versions or in continuous versions. Do we need some actions to redress these?

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the two tags ought to be synonyms, but maybe someone here has good reasons to keep them separate...

Comment: Good question. If by usage the two are effectively synonyms, then I agree with J.M. that they should be merged.